# Is there a Cleaner Dapper way to Update only columns that changed with Dapper?

Tags: dapper

I'm looking for a way to update only set properties in Dapper. i.e Update an Entity's property only if its not null.

I'm solving the same problem with a rather crude approach as shown below but I believe there should be a cleaner dapper way of doing this.

```
 public void UpdateCustomer(Customer cust)
    {
        try
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("UPDATE CUSTOMER_SETUP  SET DATE_MODIFIED = @DATE_MODIFIED ");
           if(cust.BUSINESSNAME != null) sb.Append(",BUSINESSNAME = @BUSINESSNAME ");
            if (cust.BUSINESS_ADDRESS != null) sb.Append(",BUSINESS_ADDRESS = @BUSINESS_ADDRESS ");
            if (cust.CONTACT_NAME != null) sb.Append(",CONTACT_NAME = @CONTACT_NAME ");
            if (cust.CONTACT_TITLE != null) sb.Append(",CONTACT_TITLE = @CONTACT_TITLE ");
            if (cust.CONTACT_PHONE1 != null) sb.Append(",CONTACT_PHONE1 = @CONTACT_PHONE1 ");
            if (cust.CONTACT_PHONE2 != null) sb.Append(",CONTACT_PHONE2 = @CONTACT_PHONE2 ");
            if (cust.CONTACT_EMAIL != null) sb.Append(",CONTACT_EMAIL = @CONTACT_EMAIL ");
            if (cust.CONTACT_URL != null) sb.Append(",CONTACT_URL = @CONTACT_URL ");
            if (cust.DATE_CREATED != null) sb.Append(",DATE_CREATED = @DATE_CREATED ");
            if (cust.CUSTOMER_TYPE != null) sb.Append(",CUSTOMER_TYPE = @CUSTOMER_TYPE ");
            if (cust.SUBSCRIPTION_TYPE != null) sb.Append(",SUBSCRIPTION_TYPE = @SUBSCRIPTION_TYPE ");


            sb.Append("WHERE ID = @ID ");
            sb.Append("; SELECT CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() as int ");

            var sql = sb.ToString();


            using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectString))
            {
                connection.Execute(sql, cust);

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Comment: dapper's core very deliberately doesn't include a full change tracker; however, "dapper.contrib" includes some hooks for this. I can't comment on how they behave - I haven't needed to use them

Comment: This isn't full Change tracking per se. Change tracking requires comparing the values of the entity to see if there any changes. This presupposes that the old state is somehow loaded. The feature i was looking for is a much simpler version of that...update only non null properties of an entity.

Answer (score 7):

The feature you are looking for is called Change Tracking. This feature is one of the part of a bigger Unit Of Work pattern.

Dapper do not support Change Tracking.

There are few add-ons of Dapper those support this at different level. Refer <s>[this](https://blog.falafel.com/implementing-a-generic-repository-with-dapper-extensions/)</s> [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20160807040540/http://blog.falafel.com/implementing-a-generic-repository-with-dapper-extensions/) blog post for comparison chart. As mentioned in chart, Dapper.Contrib and Dapper.Rainbow support it in different ways.

As @MarcGravell said in comment, `null` values for POCO properties is common. It does not always mean "do not update that field". That may also mean "set that DB field to `null` (or `DBNull`)". As there is no one guaranteed meaning for the property value being `null`, most ORMs implement it same way as Dapper does.

Comment: This isn't full Change tracking per se. Change tracking requires comparing the values of the entity to see if there any changes. This presupposes that the old state is somehow loaded. The feature i was looking for is a much simpler version of that...update only non null properties of an entity.

Comment: @oliverdejohnson in *general terms*: values being null is not unusual or unexpected, and people would get confused if a data layer never set things to `null` - so that (i.e. "is it null; if so: don't set") isn't how they are usually implemented

Answer (score 4):

We wrap Dapper.Rainbow's `Snapshotter` to work like a change tracker.  You need an instance of the db object for it to work.

It works perfectly for us delivering a dictionary you could quite easily use to generate the SQL you're after.

It might look something like this:

```
public class Foo{public string Name{get;set;}}

var foo = new Foo();

    var snapshotter = Snapshotter.Start(foo);

    foo.Name = "A new name";

    var dynparams = snapshotter.Diff(); //we basically wrap the snapshotter to give a dict here, but it's basically the same thing

    foreach(var name in dynparams.ParameterNames){
    sb.Append($",{name} = @{dynparams[name]} ");
    }
```

Comment: I'll be checking the Dapper.Rainbow out. I'm hoping I can get via Nuget.Will review this and see if it solves the problem in a neater way. Thanks

Comment: You could really just pull out the snapshotter class separately without having to download all of dapper.rainbow.https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/blob/master/Dapper.Rainbow/Snapshotter.cs

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but this is not much different than OP is already doing. OP is checking `null` for each property. With your way, OP get list (Dictionary?) of properties those are modified. Only benefit is that, OP need not to check all properties. **Drawback is that, OP have to find good location for `Start` and `Diff`**. This is similar to implementing UoW. If this is the case, why not bypass Dapper and use the ORM that supports UoW/Change Tracking out of the box?

Comment: I think the big difference is that this is handling all and any changes for you without your having to manually check for nullness.  Furthermore, there may be value types that simply haven't changed and therefore wouldn't need to be updated either...this handles that.

There are additional benefits to having a dictionary of properties changed...e.g. recording in a log properties changed by a particular customer.  All of this is automated here so it is much cleaner than having to account for that for every property of every class.

Answer (score 0):

Roll your own.

Add a private collection to the model, and copy the data when reading.  Compare old to new, when updating.  Build the SQL statement as needed.

Would there be a net performance gain by adding to the pre-database processing, over letting the columns "dry fire" to the database vendor?  I think most database vendors are aware when the column data is unchanged, and will exclude these columns where necessary, such as an update trigger on specific columns.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example of Update query using **Dapper** that you want. It might help you.

```
public async Task<bool> UpdateDataByIdAsync(Data data)
    {          
        using MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("your connection string");
        const string sqlQuery = @"Update Datas Set name = @name, description = @description, tags = @tags
                where data_id = @data_id;";

        var rowAffected = await connection.ExecuteAsync(sqlQuery, data);
        return rowAffected > 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet found on Github, if you are using SimpleCrud

```
/// <summary>
    /// Updates table T with the values in param.
    /// The table must have a key named "Id" and the value of id must be included in the "param" anon object. The Id value is used as the "where" clause in the generated SQL
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">Type to update. Translates to table name</typeparam>
    /// <param name="connection"></param>
    /// <param name="param">An anonymous object with key=value types</param>
    /// <returns>The Id of the updated row. If no row was updated or id was not part of fields, returns null</returns>
    public static object UpdateFields<T>(this IDbConnection connection, object param, IDbTransaction transaction = null, int? commandTimeOut = null, CommandType? commandType = null)
    {
        var names = new List<string>();
        object id = null;

        foreach (PropertyDescriptor property in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(param))
        {
            if (!"Id".Equals(property.Name, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                names.Add(property.Name);
            else
                id = property.GetValue(param);
        }

        if (id != null && names.Count > 0)
        {
            var sql = string.Format("UPDATE {1} SET {0} WHERE Id=@Id", string.Join(",", names.Select(t => { t = t + "=@" + t; return t; })), GetTableName(typeof(T)));
            if (Debugger.IsAttached)
                Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("UpdateFields: {0}", sql));
            return connection.Execute(sql, param, transaction, commandTimeOut, commandType) > 0 ? id : null;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static object UpdateFields<T>(this IDbConnection connection, object fields, CommandDefinition commandDefinition)
    {
        return UpdateFields<T>(connection, fields, commandDefinition.Transaction, commandDefinition.CommandTimeout, commandDefinition.CommandType);
    }
```